# Why is Postfix sending private information?

Tags: linux, postfix, thunderbird

My (external) webserver has postfix installed. I use it as a SMTP server for my private email. I'm currently investigating a problem where hotmail/outlook/live sees incoming email from me as spam, even though everything is setup correctly (DKIM, SPF, DMARC).

To investigate, I examined the message header of my email on outlook. And much to my surprise (and dismay), I saw a lot of private information:

```
Received: from [192.168.1.100] (xxx-xxx-xxx-xx.cable.dynamic.v4.ziggo.nl [xxx.xxx.xxx.xx])
(Authenticated sender: <my login name>)
by <my mail server> (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id E40C25F8CA
for <xxxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com>; Tue, 12 Mar 2024 09:00:32 +0100 (CET)
```

First of all, it sends my LAN address (192.168.1.100). I don't even know **how** it knows my LAN address (since the mail server and my PC are on completely different networks). It also sends my WAN address, but the worst thing is that it sends my postfix login name.

Why is postfix sending all this info? Or is it my mail client (Thunderbird) which is adding this?

How can I stop postfix from sending all this?

Answer (score 2):

Notice the IP address appears in square brackets.

It is required to put IP addresses into square brackets if used as a HELO name, as described in [RFC2821 4.3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2821#section-4.1.3). So, it's an indication that **your MUA** (Thunderbird or whatever) **is using an IP address as HELO/EHLO name during (E)SMTP session**.

Notice also that Postfix then logs the IP address it sees a connection from (your public IP, after NAT).

You can hide the user name used for SASL authentication `(Authenticated sender: <my login name>)` with [smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header):

```
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = no
```

It's disabled by default; the presence of this information in the message headers means somebody enabled this setting explicitly.

Comment: Aaahhh... That explains a lot (HELO/EHLO and why my login name is there). I've set up postfix myself but really can't remember why I would have enabled that.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is postfix sending all this info?

It is *required* [to send your IP address](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321#section-3.7.2). IMHO including your SMTP AUTH username is a bit excessive - but useful for analytics. OTOH:

- usernames are not secrets
- SMTP does not conceal the originating address (although it used to be trivial to forge this). I would be extremely wary of any messaging system that did

Comment: Usernames are not secrets, but in this case it may directly hint potential abuser *what* user names to brute force on *which* server.

Comment: Treating usernames as secrets is a very inneffective solution against brute force attacks. If you post a new question on this here or another stackoverflow site you might get some sensible answers about how to address such attacks.

Answer (score 0):

The postfix daemon/process binds itself to an ip of the network interface and use that when processing a mail. It also does a lookup on your public ip so the receiving mail server knows from which ip the mail is coming.
That's just default behavior and by design

Comment: Yes I understand that. But 192.168.1.100 is my local LAN address. At home. My webserver is not in my local network. It's not even in the same city. Also, why would it send my postfix login name in the header? That seems like a huge security issue.

Comment: It's included because an mail ls send by a user,in this case a system user.

Comment: Hmmm yeah, but it's a security issue since it makes life a lot easier for a malicious individual trying a brute force attack against my mail server (since he now only needs to brute force the password).

Comment: That's not a security issue but a configuration on your side, your not suppose to send mail using system users but virtual mailbox users

Comment: @Zippy1970 If someone can brute force your password over an internet connection, you shouldn't be administrating servers until you understand how to administrate password policies.

Comment: @Paul Of course they can't simply brute force passwords on my server. There are quite a few things in place to prevent that. But knowing a user name is one less hurdle for someone with malicious intent. Plus it gives them an incentive to try. If you give me your birth date, I still can't steal your identity. But it's one needed piece that I then no longer need to pursue.